# SMBfile.listfiles() gives up "The network name cannot be found."

Tags: smb, jcifs

Creating a java standalone application for copying files from one share drive to another share drive using JCIFS. Prior to copy I should place a NTLM authentication. I get the error as "The network name cannot be found" while listing files using SMBfile.listfiles()

```
sourceAuth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(sourceUsername+":"+sourcePassword);

currentFolder = new SmbFile(dirToList, sourceAuth);

listofFiles = currentFolder.listFiles();
```

Consider the network path is \Myserver\Share\FileName.Ext, I could properly access it in windows explorer.

But in code, the SMB URL smb://Myserver/Share/FileName.Ext results in "The network name cannot be found"

If i'm trying to use IPC$ in between - smb://Myserver/IPC$/Share/FileName.Ext resulting me in "Invalid operation for IPC service".

Comment: same problem at the moment. Do you found a solution ?